# \Exception does not catch exception with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, try-catch

I have the following method:

```
function fooAction(Request $request){
    $response = new Response();

    try{
        // Doing some stuff
        return $response;
    }

    catch(\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {
        $response->setStatusCode(500);
        $response->setContent($e->getMessage());
    }

    catch(\Exception $e ){
        $response->setStatusCode(500);
        $response->setContent($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $response;
}
```

When I call it I get a status code 500 with empty message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you get a 500 error from another place. Commenting out `setStatusCode` will result in a 500 too.

Comment: Are you working in dev or in prod environment? Try putting a die()  in the catch block

Comment: @ste I'm working in prod environment

Comment: @schellingerht If I comment all code inside fooAction() and I just add `echo "Hello";` works ok. I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: The problem is that in prod environment you only get a generic 500 error, unless you handle it in other ways. Try inserting `die("something");`  in the catch block and see what's happening. 
See also http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html